# Basic Maths C# Not Working

Tags: c#, math

Why won't either of these work in C# ??

```
// Expected: 0.5, Output: 0

Console.WriteLine("Result #1: " + (50 / 100));

int iFifty = 50;
int iOneHundred = 100;
Console.WriteLine("Result #2: " + (iFifty / iOneHundred));
```

Comment: For future reference, "not working " tells us very little about the problem you're running into. Compile errors? Runtime exception? What are they? Have you Googled the error to find out what it is and why it's happening? Or is it unexpected behavior? What happened? What did you expect to happen? What have you attempted to fix this already? Please elaborate.

Comment: It *does* work.  It works just fine.  It prints `Result #2: 0`, just like it's supposed to.

Comment: @tnw Actually, it's not obvious, but it is there: OP has the expected and actual output in a comment at the top of the code.

Answer (score 5):

it is an integer division, you need doubles:

```
Console.WriteLine("Result #1: " + (50 / 100d));
```

Or:

```
Console.WriteLine("Result #1: " + (50 / 100.0));
```

If both operands are `integer`, an *integer division* is performing therefore you get an `integer` result.If you use `'d'` literal you explicitly state that number should be considered as `double` and other operand is promoted to `double` automatically, then a double division is performing and you get the correct result.See [`C# Specification Section 2.4.4 Literals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664672%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more info about literals and also you migh want take a look at [`Floating-Point Types in C#`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're dividing `int`s rather than `float`s or `double`s. Try:

```
50 / 100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use float or double data type because integer doesn't calculate values in points.

```
float iFifty = 50;
float iOneHundred = 100;
Console.WriteLine("Result #2: " + (iFifty / iOneHundred));
```

OR

```
double iFifty = 50;
double iOneHundred = 100;
Console.WriteLine("Result #2: " + (iFifty / iOneHundred));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your constants or variables as floating point numbers (double, float or decimal)

```
 Console.WriteLine("Result #1: " + (50.0 / 100.0));
```

The division operator to apply to your code is choosen looking at the operands.
You have integer constants and variables so the operator applies an integer division

```
double iFifty = 50.0;
double iOneHundred = 100.0;
Console.WriteLine("Result #2: " + (iFifty / iOneHundred));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division, result of which is another integer.  Integer division returns only the whole part of the division.  Since 100 is contained 0 full times in 50, you get back 0.

Cast to float or double to achieve what you are seeking:

```
Console.WriteLine("Result #1: " + ((double)50 / (double)100));
```

Comment: 50 is contained twice in 100, but 100 is contained 0 times in 50.

Answer (score 0):

this is not working mean you want to say that this gives the output 0. because you are using `integer` values.so,

you need Force a floating point quotient.

```
Console.WriteLine("Floating point quotient:    "+ (50.0 / 100.0));
```