# Calculation differ in C# and JS

Tags: javascript, c#

I got into a small confusion of numerical calculation.

in C#:

```
> 44.5 + (((5220886 / 2) - 2496118) / 897211) * 9
< 44.5
```

in JS:

```
> 44.5 + (((5220886 / 2) - 2496118) / 897211) * 9
< 45.646803817608124
```

Which one is correct? Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening?

P.S: Though there is one post in SO which is dealing with [C# floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float), my question is a little bit different as I am not doing anything with strings. This is pure numerical calculations.

Comment: C# has integers, JavaScript does not. The whole right part in C# is integer math.

Comment: That should be the correct answer, not how floats work. There’s a big difference in the calculation due to data types. Please add an answer, @Dmitry

Comment: add `.0` at the end of numbers in C# to do floating point division instead of integer division

Comment: Add a `d` after any of the divisors in the C# expression to force all operands to be evaluated as doubles, and see what happens.

Comment: and related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820057/basic-maths-c-sharp-not-working

Answer (score 3):

C# has integers, JavaScript does not. The whole right part in C# is integer math, which means that the fractions got truncated. In C# you need to add `.0` (e.g. `var x = 2.0;`, `var` is now a `double`) to the number to make it into a `double` while in JavaScript all numbers are internally represented as doubles.

Answer (score 1):

In C# when using an integer divisor, [the result is rounded towards zero](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/division-operator).

Since JavaScript does not have the same types as C#, floating point division is used instead. To have the same result in C#, add a 'd' or a '.0' to the divisor.